# vba waitOnReturn stops Excel

Tags: excel, vba, wait

I made a vba program (in Excel) in which I need the keyword waitOnReturn so my shell ends before formatting some cells.
The problem is : when the program is waiting (for the shell to end), it is impossible to use Excel on my PC, I can't modify another file, nor opening some. As the shell takes 30 minutes, it is annoying.

Is there a way to specify I want to be able to use Excel when my shell is running even if I specified waitOnReturn ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: waitOnReturn specifically means "block me until it's done". Not blocking self while it's being done is achieved by not using waitOnReturn.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I'll look after another solution to deal with my constraints.